# How do I get python to recognize the correct substring in a string?

Tags: python

Sorry for the noobish question, first real time working with python.
I'm trying to make a card game and I have a list of card values saved as strings like `"Diamond_Ace","Diamonds_1","Diamonds_Jack"` and so on.
I have a function

```
def cardval(card):
    if "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9" or "10" in card:
        return int(re.findall("\d+",card)[0])
    if "Jack" or "Queen" or "King" in card:
        return 10
    if "Ace" in card:
        return 1
```

The problem is the first if statement is always triggered, even if the card contains a face card and an error is thrown when it can't find an int value in the string.
Any help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add else statement .. not new if statement . Also you can use range instead of using so many OR conditions.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had a range originally but thought that might be causing the problem

Comment: @lostin while this would make it more readable maybe, this is not the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first `if` statement is, is that you evaluate the truth values of `"1"`, `"2"`, etc. which are all true.

You have to repeat the `in card` every time:

```
def cardval(card):
    if "2" in card or "3" in card or "4" in card: # etc.
        return int(re.findall("\d+",card)[0])
    # etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change:

```py
if "2" or "3" or ... in card:
```

to:

```py
if "2" in card or "3" in card or ...:
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```py
def cardval(card):
    card_digit = re.findall("\d+",card)
    if card_digit:
        return card_digit[0]
    elif "Ace" in card:
        return 1
    else:
        return 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement should be like this:

```
if "2" in card or "3" in card or "4" .....:
```

You can also do it in a more Pythonic way:

```
if any(str(x) in card for x in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]):
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answer, you could also do something like:

```
>>> card = ['Diamond_Ace', 'Diamonds_1', 'Diamonds_Jack']
>>> if any(i.endswith(('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10')) for i in card):
...     print('Found it')
... 
>>> if any(i.endswith(('Jack', 'Queen', 'King')) for i in card):
...     print('Found it')
... 
Found it
>>> if any(i.endswith('Ace') for i in card):
...     print('Found it')
... 
Found it
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use many `OR` operations in a single line. Then you can use `any` builtin function

```
if any(i in card for i in ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']):
    # This will be True if any of the element exists in card
```

If you want to perform multiple and operations then you can use `all` builtin function

```
if all(i in card for i in ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']):
    # This will be true only if all item exists in card
```